# Solid front axle squeak while steering in wet conditions

Tags: jeep, steering

I have had a squeak when I turn my steering wheel for about 6 months now, and it's driving my insane.  The squeak shows up after a day in the rain, and lasts about a week after the last time driving in wet conditions.

I checked all the standard places for a squeak such as the steering stabilizer and trackbar joints by removing them one at a time turning the wheel.  Neither of them were the culprit, so I assumed it was my tie-rod.  I ordered a new tie rod online and installed it yesterday.  To my dismay the squeak is still there.

It's really hard to pinpoint, but it seems to be coming from the passenger wheel area.  What other parts involved with steering could be causing the squeak?

I put some poly bushings in my control arms 18months ago, but I don't see how those (which are just supposed to move up and down) could be causing a squeak while steering.

There's no noise when it's dry, but after a day of driving in the rain, or four wheeling in mud/water it tends to squeak for a few days.

This noise is annoying and embarrassing, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Could you try to jack up the front end, unlock the steering, move the wheels back and forth, spray it with the hose and move the wheels again?

Comment: +! for the hose idea

Comment: Also, what year/model/engine of Jeep do you have? Stock or modified (if so, how)?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 2004 Jeep TJ.  Mostly stock, but have replace trakcbar, one LCA, all the control arm bushings, and tie rod.  Along with 1.25" "lift" in the front for leveling.  For the most part everything is stock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't mention checking the ball joints (which are usually greasable) which are at the top and bottom of the knuckle or the U-joints on the axle shafts. Those are the most likely candidates.

Comment: That was the problem.  Took the better portion of a day to replace, but the steering is noticeable smoother and the god forsaken squeek is finally gone.

Answer (score 0):

My money is on the power steering pump belt being loose.  In wet conditions this will squeal, it'll do it when the pump is placed under load (when turning the wheel) and do it worst when the steering rack is at the limit of it's travel.

It wouldn't surprise me if the pump is located near the passenger side wheel well.